# Output of a python script read into C program without creating a temporary file to pass the value between program

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, gtk

I am using `system("calling python script")` <- this is called in c program. In the script I am just checking if two arrays match then return this

The line below is triggered from C program

Then I read the system return value is which just returns 0. All i want to do is pass a value from python to C program without using a temporary file between them.

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buffer[300];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "xls2csv %s > /home/......../xyz.py", filename);

int systemReturn = system(buffer);

if(systemReturn == -1)
{
    // The system method failed
    fprintf(stderr, "Error");
}
if(systemReturn = 2 )
{
    //Then do this
}
```

python program:

```
if(Data_in_end != merged):
    print("They did not match")
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    print("They did match")
    sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: Is `xls2csv` the Python script?

Comment: The code you've posted is very incomplete, where is the temporary file being used?

Comment: It's unclear, but I think you should be using pipes.

Comment: Hey Barmar, The xls2csv is nothing to do with python script. I just types a random string for example. The code above is just a small scale example. There is no temporary file in use. I want to pass data back to c withoutut using temporary files.

Comment: Use `popen("python scriptname.py", "r")` to run the Python script and read its standard output.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass a little bit of data between programs, you can use arguments. For example, the linux `shutdown` command will shut your computer off in one minute by default. However, if you pass it the argument "now" (`shutdown now`), it will turn off immediately.

in your c program, you will need a specially formatted main function that accepts arguments. There are hundreds of examples online. This approach is not recommended for large amounts of data.

Comment: How would arguments be used to pass information from the Python script back to the C program?